# EF - How to make (composite) foreign key optional

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have 3 models: Order, Organisation and OrderOrganisation.

OrderOrganisation's existence is not mandatory... but I don't know how to tell EF.

Currently, if I write queries it is using inner joins instead of outer joins to join to OrderOrganisation.

I would like to do it as part of the model (if possible) and not in the context (as it's a large database and I think using the context fragments to logic).

Here are my models.

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OrderOrganisation> OrderOrganisations { get; set; }
}

public class Organisation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OrderOrganisation> OrderOrganisations { get; set; }
}

public class OrderOrganisation
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int OrganisationId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OrderId")]
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OrganisationId")]
    public virtual Organisation Organisation { get; set; }
}
```

What do I need to include please?

I presume I need to make something nullable, but I can't work out what.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to create cross table on such a case on EF. Below code is enough for you I think

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Organisation> OrderOrganisations { get; set; }
}

public class Organisation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Order> OrderOrganisations { get; set; }
}
```

Then EF will create you OrganisationOrders named table.

Comment: The tables already exist. I need to get it to work with EF without making changes to the db.

Comment: If db is already created why don't you just use db first? Leave it to Visual Studio to create classes.

Comment: Because the database doesn't contain all necessary foreign keys etc